# Background showing between divs

Tags: html, css, image, background, position

There is background colour showing between image divs. I thought it might have something to do with margins. Even setting the div to `absolute` positioning and the parent to `relative` doesn't work. The picture still won't show without it being relative. (`robot2.jpg` in div `sec`, `sectThree`).

Here's the website: [thomasogbourne.me](http://thomasogbourne.me)

```css
html,
body {
  margin: 0px;
  height: 100%;
  margin-top: 0px;
  margin-right: 0px;
  margin-left: 0px;
  background-color: #000000;
}

h1,
h2,
h3,
h4,
h5,
h6,
p {
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}


/*
nav {
 position: fixed;
 width: 100%;
 height: 50px;
 background-color: rgba(0,0,0,.5);
 z-index: 99;
 text-align: center;
 
}

nav a {
 text-decoration: none;
 color: #fff;
 margin-left: 30px;
 line-height: 50px;
 
}*/

.sect {
  position: rela;
  height: 100%;
  background-size: cover;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
}

.subSection {
  height: 30%;
}

.smallsubSection {
  height: 20%;
}

.sectOne {
  background-image: url("/Images/CX750Msmall.jpg");
  background-attachment: fixed;
}

.sectTwo {
  background-image: url("/Images/drone.jpg");
  position: relative;
  top: -90px;
  z-index: -1
}

.sectThree {
  background-image: url("/Images/robot2.jpg");
  position: absolute;
  top: -150px;
  background-repeat: space;
}

#aboutSection {
  background: #648880;
  background: linear-gradient(to right, #f6f1d3, #648880 85%, #293f50);
}

#gearSection {
  background: #0083FF;
  background: linear-gradient(#3943DA, #00F3FF);
  height: 66%;
}

#contactSection {
  background: #648880;
  background: linear-gradient(#DEDEDE, #898989 85%);
}

.smallsubSection {
  font-family: "Arial Narrow", Arial, sans-serif;
  font-size: 24px;
  font-style: normal;
  font-variant: normal;
  font-weight: 500;
  line-height: 26.4px;
}

#bigname {
  font-family: "Luckiest Guy";
  font-size: 45px;
  font-style: normal;
  font-variant: normal;
  font-weight: 500;
  line-height: 26.4px;
  letter-spacing: 2px;
  text-decoration: overline underline;
  color: #D5D5D5;
  text-align: center;
  position: absolute;
  top: 33%;
  left: 50%;
  margin-right: -50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}


/* MENU START */

nav.container {
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 30px 3em;
  background-color: #000040;
  position: fixed;
  width: 40%;
  text-align: center;
  list-style: none;
  margin-left: 27.5%;
  z-index: 1;
}

nav.container a {
  color: #fff;
  text-decoration: none;
  margin: 0 10px;
  padding: 10px 10px;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 0;
  cursor: pointer;
  font-family: "Rockwell Extra Bold", "Rockwell Bold", monospace;
  font-size: 25px;
  padding: 10px;
}

nav.borderXwidth a:before,
nav.borderXwidth a:after {
  position: absolute;
  opacity: 0;
  width: 0%;
  height: 2px;
  content: '';
  background: #FFF;
  transition: all 0.3s;
}

nav.borderXwidth a:before {
  left: 0px;
  top: 0px;
}

nav.borderXwidth a:after {
  right: 0px;
  bottom: 0px;
}

nav.borderXwidth a:hover:before,
nav.borderXwidth a:hover:after {
  opacity: 1;
  width: 100%;
}


/* MENU END */

.button {
  background-color: #4CAF50;
  /* Green */
  border: none;
  color: white;
  padding: 13px 21px;
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: 24px;
  margin: 4px 2px;
  cursor: pointer;
  transition-duration: 0.4s;
  position: relative;
  bottom: -90px;
  -moz-border-radius: 10px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 10px;
  width: 150px;
}

.button1 {
  box-shadow: 0 8px 16px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2), 0 6px 20px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.19);
}

.button2:hover {
  box-shadow: 0 12px 16px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.24), 0 17px 50px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.19);
}


/* SCROLLING TEXT MAIN SECTION */

.content {
  position: absolute;
  top: 144%;
  left: 54%;
  -webkit-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  font-size: 35px;
  line-height: 40px;
  font-family: 'Lato', sans-serif;
  color: #ecf0f1;
  height: 160px;
  overflow: hidden;
  zoom: 3.5;
  -moz-transform: scale(3.5);
}

.visible {
  font-weight: 600;
  overflow: hidden;
  height: 40px;
  padding: 0 40px;
}

.visible:before {
  content: '';
  left: 0;
  line-height: 40px;
}

.visible:after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  right: -80px;
  line-height: 40px;
}

.visible:after,
.visible:before {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  color: #16a085;
  font-size: 42px;
  -webkit-animation-name: opacity;
  -webkit-animation-duration: 2s;
  -webkit-animation-iteration-count: infinite;
  -webkit-animation-name: opacity;
  animation-name: opacity;
  -webkit-animation-duration: 2s;
  animation-duration: 2s;
  -webkit-animation-iteration-count: infinite;
  animation-iteration-count: infinite;
}

p {
  display: inline;
  float: left;
  margin: 0;
  left: 40px;
}

ul {
  margin-top: 0;
  padding-left: 230px;
  text-align: left;
  list-style: none;
  -webkit-animation-name: change;
  -webkit-animation-duration: 6s;
  -webkit-animation-iteration-count: infinite;
  -webkit-animation-name: change;
  animation-name: change;
  -webkit-animation-duration: 6s;
  animation-duration: 6s;
  -webkit-animation-iteration-count: infinite;
  animation-iteration-count: infinite;
}

ul li {
  line-height: 40px;
  margin: 0;
}

li {
  width: 270px
}

@-webkit-keyframes opacity {
  0%,
  100% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  50% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
}

@-webkit-keyframes change {
  0%,
  12%,
  100% {
    -webkit-transform: translateY(0);
    transform: translateY(0);
  }
  17%,
  29% {
    -webkit-transform: translateY(-25%);
    transform: translateY(-25%);
  }
  34%,
  46% {
    -webkit-transform: translateY(-50%);
    transform: translateY(-50%);
  }
  51%,
  63% {
    -webkit-transform: translateY(-75%);
    transform: translateY(-75%);
  }
  68%,
  80% {
    -webkit-transform: translateY(-50%);
    transform: translateY(-50%);
  }
  85%,
  97% {
    -webkit-transform: translateY(-25%);
    transform: translateY(-25%);
  }
}

@keyframes opacity {
  0%,
  100% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  50% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
}

@keyframes change {
  0%,
  12%,
  100% {
    -webkit-transform: translateY(0);
    transform: translateY(0);
  }
  17%,
  29% {
    -webkit-transform: translateY(-25%);
    transform: translateY(-25%);
  }
  34%,
  46% {
    -webkit-transform: translateY(-50%);
    transform: translateY(-50%);
  }
  51%,
  63% {
    -webkit-transform: translateY(-75%);
    transform: translateY(-75%);
  }
  68%,
  80% {
    -webkit-transform: translateY(-50%);
    transform: translateY(-50%);
  }
  85%,
  97% {
    -webkit-transform: translateY(-25%);
    transform: translateY(-25%);
  }
}
```

```html
<body>

  <nav class="container borderXwidth">

    <a id="home" href="#homeSection">HOME</a>
    <a id="about" href="#aboutSection">ABOUT</a>
    <a id="gear" href="#gearSection">MY GEAR</a>
    <a id="portfolio" href="#portfolioSection">PORTFOLIO</a>
    <a id="contact" href="#contactSection">CONTACT</a>

  </nav>

  <div id="homeSection" class="sect 
sectOne">

    <div id="bigname">
      <h1>
        THOMAS OGBOURNE
      </h1>
      <a href="#aboutSection"> <button class="button button2 hvr-icon-hang hvr-fade">Begin</button></a>
    </div>
  </div>`

  <div id="aboutSection" class="subSection">
    <div class='content'>
      <div class='visible'>
        <p>
          Hello I'm Tom:
        </p>
        <ul>
          <li>Web Developer</li>
          <li>Gamer</li>
          <li>Student</li>
          <li>Computer Guy</li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div id="serviceSection" class="sect 
sectTwo"></div>
  <div id="gearSection" class="subSection2"></div>
  <div id="portfolioSection" class="sect 
sectThree"></div>
  <div id="contactSection" class="smallsubSection">
    <h2 style="margin-top:0;">
      Email: *******************
    </h2>
    <h2>
      Phone: **************
    </h2>
  </div>

  <script src="js/jquery-3.1.1.min.js"></script>

  <script src="js/app.js"></script>
</body>
```

Comment: I guess, by mistake u are added  ' after closing homeSection Div.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is this what you wanted? :

https://jsfiddle.net/n3h3cm1x/

Basically your code is very messy and chaotic. there is something like this in there:

```
<a href="#aboutSection"> <button class="button button2 hvr-icon-hang hvr-fade">Begin</button></a>
            </div>
        </div>`




        <div id="aboutSection" class="subSection">
            <div class='content'>
```

Notice that ` symbol? that was the cause of the first break between divs.

the second break between divs is

```
top:-90px;
```

which you added to few sections at the bottom.

Comment: Yes! thankyou so much, however the last image now doesnt show, is that because of the positioning?

Comment: UPDATE: by setting the third image to relative it appears but with the last break between divs returning?

Comment: @ThomasOgbourne remove all 'top: -90' and 'top:-150'. Also if that helped, mark the answer as solved ;)

Comment: @ThomasOgbourne no problem dude. Keep it up!